# Tomcat CORS not working in FireFox

Tags: ajax, firefox, tomcat, cors

I have a REST API deployed on Tomcat 8.0.15, I added a CORS filter in order to activate cross domain requests.

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
    <param-value>ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposedHeaders</param-name>
    <param-value>DAV, content-length, Allow</param-value>
</init-param>

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Client side :

```
function testF3(){

         var user = { "login": "test", "password": "test*1" }   ;
         $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',

              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              url: 'https://xxxxxx/login',// Use xxxx to mask the URL
              crossDomain: true,
              data: JSON.stringify( user ),
              dataType:'text',            
              success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('Fired');
                        console.log(errorThrown+" //  "+textStatus);
                        }
            }); 

    }
```

Everything is working fine, I have tested this in Chrome 40.0.2214.115 ,Opera 28.0.1750.40 and Safari 5.1.7 and get the result as expected.

I did the same thing with FireFox 36.0.1 but I got errors in the console stating that OPTIONS request was aborted. Please check the image below for more details :

[image]

I tried in vain to change the CORS filter in my web.xml, add and remove supported Headers .. But no result...

Please any help will be very appreciated.

Many thanks guys.